# Unity3d MeshRender

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use C# to disable and enable the `MeshRender` component in Unity3d however I am getting the following error,

> error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `UnityEngine.GameObject.GetComponent(System.Type)'

The line of code I am using is below. I'm using this in the same function.

```
MeshRenderer showZone = GameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
```

Also I'm posting here rather than Unity Answers as I get a far faster response here and it's always useful information regardless of the outcome.

Comment: GameObject is a class, you need an instance of an object to use the GetComponent method. For instance this.GetComponent<>() would work.

Comment: try MeshRenderer showZone = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>(); instead

Answer (score 18):

You're having trouble with several problems. First, you are trying to use `GetComponent<>` on a class instead of an instance of an object. This leads directly to your second problem. After searching for a specific `GameObject` you're not using the result and you're trying to disable the renderer of the `GameObject` containing the script. Third, C# is case-sensitive, `Renderer` is a class while `renderer` is a reference to an instance of `Renderer` attached to the `GameObject`

This code snippet combines everything: find the `GameObject` and disable its renderer

```
GameObject go = GameObject.FindWithTag("zone1");
if (go != null) { // the result could be null if no matching GameObject is found
  go.renderer.enabled = false;
}
```

You could use `go.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;` instead of `go.renderer. enabled = false;` But by using `renderer` you don't need to know what kind of renderer is used by the `GameObject`. It could be a `MeshRenderer` or a `SpriteRenderer` for example, `renderer` always points to the renderer used by the `GameObject`, if there exists one.

Comment: You are absolutely right, must be choosen as an answer

Comment: As an aside, the part about if (go != null) can be alternatively written as:  go.renderer.enabled = (go == null);

Comment: @MaxvonHippel no, that's not the same. If `go` is null and you try to set `go.renderer.enabled` a `NullReferenceException` will be thrown.

Comment: oh right, I didn't think of that.  Thanks @StefanHoffmann. Everyone else, don't do what I recommended haha

Answer (score 2):

My friend. Just try use lowercase `gameObject` instead of `GameObject` and `renderer` instead of `Renderer`

The main problem that you try access Static class variable, using the name of class instead of class instance.
Class names here are `GameObject` and `Renderer`
And instances are `gameObject` and `renderer`

Answer (score 2):

```
MeshRenderer showZone = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
```

delete the 'GameObject.'

GameObject is a type. What you want is in an instance of a gameObject to call GetcComponent on. Thats what the error is about.

Which for note, this:

```
MeshRenderer showZone = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
```

is the exact same as this:

```
MeshRenderer showZone = this.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
```

You are calling GetComponent on the GameObject instance of which the script is attached to.

Answer (score 2):

your code should look like this:

```
MeshRenderer showZone = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Like others already wrote, you need to get an instantiated `GameObject`. You call the base class `GameObject` where only static functions can be called which do not need a `GameObject` in the `SceneView`.

**`gameObject`** IS AN instance.You get the instance of the `GameObject` the `Monobehaviour` is added to. Calling the function `GetComponent` without any object is the same as:

- `this`
- `gameObject`

---

`GameObject` IS NO instance.

Be careful at the first letter!

Answer (score 0):

Look documentation:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void Example() {
        renderer.enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Link: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-enabled.html
Changing of programming languages upper-right.

Comment: I've tried this. I don't think it works as it's an external script changing multiple objects meshrenderer settings via an ID given in the editor. I'll give this a shot after trying LearnCocos2D's response.

Comment: Trying something like this gives me an error of:

`error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `UnityEngine.Renderer.enabled'`

Here is an example of how I'm using this:

`if(random > 0f && random < 2f){
    id = 1;
    GameObject.FindWithTag("zone" + id);
    Renderer.enabled = true;
   }`

Answer (score 0):

2 ways you can solve the Problem either. You add the word static to the method that is calling your statement.

ex : 
    public static GetTheMesh(){}

I do not recommend on doing this cause. If you have other calls inside the method that needs to access Instance, this will cause you trouble.

Second way of fixing it is make a pointer or reference first before getting the component. Or use the GameObject.Find <= which is slow if.

```
showZone = GameObject.Find("TheGameObjectName").GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the renderer on this gameObject then use:

```
this.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
```

If it's not this gameObject then use:

```
GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("your_tag").GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
```

Or you could give the object manually:

```
public GameObject go;
go.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-enabled.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use two types of peace of code for access MeshRenderer enable and disable

1> create GetMeshRenderer script (script name as you want) attached to empty game-object into the scene and assign Cube or sphere or any 3d object as u want to enable and disable.

************************************** Code ***************************

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GetMeshRenderer : MonoBehaviour 
{
public MeshRenderer ShowZone;

void Start () 
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{

    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Y))
    {
        ShowZone.enabled = true;    
    }

    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.N))
    {
        ShowZone.enabled = false;   
    }

}
```

}

---

2>

attach below peace of code script to any 3d object like sphere ,cube

***************************  code  ***************************

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class GetMeshRenderer : MonoBehaviour 
 {
   private MeshRenderer ShowZone;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    ShowZone = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer> (); 
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{

    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Y))
    {
        ShowZone.enabled = true;         
    }

    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.N))
    {
        ShowZone.enabled = false;   
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using `GameObject` which is just a class that "describes" what it is. What you want, if this script is attached to the GameObject who's mesh renderer you want, is `gameObject` with a lowercase "g."

If you want to get the mesh renderer of another GameObject, you can find it by name with `GameObject.Find("zone1");` (note the uppercase "G" in that one,) or you can give it a tag and find it with `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("zone1");`
(You may or may not already know that but it doesn't hurt to provide the information.)

Edit:

Your other problem is that you must use `renderer` instead of `Renderer` because, like the `GameObject` "Renderer" with a capital "R" references a class, instead of a specific object.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is `GameObject` is different from `gameobject` Gameobject is a class and gameobject is a instance of current gameobject or gameobject in which the script is attached

Replace the line

```
MeshRenderer showZone = GameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
```

with

```
MeshRenderer showZone = gameobject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
```

I think this will do,

> Also note that in your Error statement ,it is saying that GameObject is a Class or a data type not an object

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the gears? Yes? ***Click it*** and ***click*** remove component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the declaration:

```
other.gameobject.GetComponent< MeshRenderer>().Setactive (false);
```

One Line Reference...after the condition is fulfilled..

For more precise help regarding MeshRender, see the Unity Documentations..

Comment: SetActive is only for GameObject, use enable on components

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with my declaration and i just fixed it by changing "G" to "g" in gameObject and i declared it in Start so it is like...

MeshRenderer showZone = gameObject.GetComponent();